# force_download not working in codeigniter after writing

Tags: codeigniter, download

tried to auto download file after file created but its not working. file creating and appending data perfectly but download functionality not working

```html
 public function getexportfile(){
       $this->load->dbutil();
     // $this->load->database('DB_utility','dbutil');
      //$this->load->helper('download_helper','download');
        $this->load->helper('download_helper');
        $this->load->helper('file');
      error_reporting(0);
      ini_set('display_errors', 0);
      $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
      $request = json_decode($postdata);
      
       ## Condition Start  
        $sWhere = " where condition"; // where conditon 
      
       $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $filename = 'app/logs/othermarketplace_'.$date.'.csv'; 
        
        $data = $this->PMP->export($sWhere); // calling model
        
        $result = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($data);
        write_file($filename,$result);  // file creating write data perfectly
        
        $data = file_get_contents($filename);
        
        //$path    =   file_get_contents(base_url().$filename);
        //$name    =   "othermarketplace_'.$date.'.csv";
        //force_download($nme, $pth);  
        
        force_download($filename,$data);
        }
```

anything i missed?

Comment: In  `force_download($filename,$data);` $filename is name of file but in your case it's a full path  `$filename = 'app/logs/othermarketplace_'.$date.'.csv';`
change $filename  to  othermarketplace_'.$date.'.csv'

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

> // Contents of photo.jpg will be automatically read
>
> force_download('/path/to/photo.jpg', NULL);

```
    //$data = file_get_contents($filename);
    
    //$path    =   file_get_contents(base_url().$filename);
    //$name    =   "othermarketplace_'.$date.'.csv";
    //force_download($nme, $pth);  
    
    if (!is_file($filename)) {
        exit('No file found.');
    }

    force_download($filename, NULL);
```

Note:

These lines might be doing something weird. Perhaps remove them as they aren't being used:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
```

Comment: its only giving file data in response not downloading file @alex

Comment: I personally use the function like this and will get the downloaded file. I will update my question for clarity. Make sure to remove file get contents.